# How to get nodeType using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get nodeType and then compare it to where it is text node or element node.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var mm= $('.jj')
    alert(mm.nodeValue)
    })
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="jj">value</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try to access to those properties with

```
var mm = $('.jj').get(0);
alert(mm.nodeValue);
alert(mm.nodeType)
```

Comment: @amit `get(0)` returns the native DOM element from the jQuery object, allowing you to use get the native javascript `nodeValue` and `nodeType` properties from it.

Comment: because `nodeValue` and `nodeType` are properties of the DOM nodes while `$('.jj')` return a `jQuery` object, that's why you need to use `get()`

Comment: `nodeValue` will be `null` since `.jj` is always element node.

Comment: when i am trying to get nodeValue it give me null, i want to access text of div

Comment: Can you please share some text node example

Comment: @Carlos to get text inside div use .textContent or .innerText

Answer (score 8):

I know it wasn't the question, but to see what type it is (DIV, SPAN, etc), use tagName.

```
var mm = $('.jj').get(0);
alert(mm.tagName);
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the DOM Node you can use `[0]`:

```
var mm = $(".jj")[0];
if (mm.nodeType === 1) {
    // Node.ELEMENT_NODE
}
```

However, `<div>` element will never be a text node and won't have a `nodeValue`.

Text node is the first child of your `<div>` element. So the following code will give you "value":

```
alert(mm[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
```

Comment: Can you please share some text node and also how to get to know which is element node and which one is text node

Comment: @amit Here is one option: `mm[0].firstChild.nodeValue`.

Comment: One last thing i have change my html and i want to select text inside the span <div class="jj">value sdfasfsa <span>jitender</span> </div>

Comment: @amit To select or to get? In order to get text just use `var text = $("span").text();`.

Comment: But i want access this through nodes

Comment: Then use the same logic: `var text = $("span")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;`.

Comment: actually i want to understand this function http://jsfiddle.net/Uu3nw/  how this function access to text

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var mm= $('.jj')
    alert(mm.get(0).nodeValue)
    })
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var mm= $('.jj')
    alert(mm[0])
    })
</script>
```

Because a jquery collection is a "wrapped set" of DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, `$('.jj').get(0).nodeType` works.

Same as `$('.jj').first().nodeType`

or `$('.jj').prop('nodeType')`

> `.prop()` : Get the value of a property for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more properties for every matched element.