# iframe jquery firefox/ie weird error

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a web-app(http://phppetar.heliohost.org/htmlxray.html) that among other things finds out all the text nodes inside user-given web page (located inside iframe) and fades them out using jquery FadeTo function when someone clicks Fade button.

Everything works as expected inside Chrome, but for some reason it doesn't inside FireFox or IE... this is the error that i get from Firebug console:

*Error: Permission denied to access property 'nodeType'*

when i try to access iframe content using this code :

```
.contents().filter(function() {return (this.nodeType == 3) && ($.trim(this.data).length >0 )})
```

It's not cross-domain issue cuz i have PHP proxy that takes care of given url's ...
To make things even more weird, even on FireFox and IE everything works for some webpages(www.google.com, www.fesb.hr, www.forum.hr ....) but it doesn't for most sites that i tried, for instance www.foxnews.com, www.cnn.com, www.nbc.com, www.digg.com, www.dailymotion.com ...

I haven't find any connection between sites that work and sites that don't, they don't have same doctype, some of them include their own jquery, some don't ....

Comment: Some sites don't allow themselves to be embedded in an iframe.

Comment: i'm using local proxy ahren, but even if i was embedding original src those sites wouldn't work in Chrome either not just ff or ie...

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160772/how-to-get-nodetype-using-jquery

I tried getting the nodeType after JQuerifying `this`, and it had no errors in Firefox. It didn't seem to return any results for www.foxnews.com though.

Comment: i get the same error when i use $(this).get(0).nodeType == 3

Comment: i have found what the problem was, ff and ie don't allow access to text nodes inside iframes ... that is why it has worked with sites that don't have iframes inside them and didn't with sites that did have iframes ....