# How to detect the child element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect the type of element using jquery. Here is my scenerio

```
function editTaskField(targetElementId) {
    var element = $('#' + targetElementId);
    var fieldValue = element.val();
    var fieldName = element.attr('data-field-name');
    var taskId = $('#task_id').val();
    $.ajax({
        'url': '/project/ajax/updatetaskfield',
        'type': 'POST',
        'dataType': 'JSON',
        'data': {
            'field_name': fieldName,
            'field_value': fieldValue,
            'task_id': taskId,
        },
        'success': function(data) {

        }
    })
}
```

In the success callback I want something like

```
'success': function(data) {
    var parentElement = element.parent('.info-value');
    if(parentElement.child().type() == 'select'){
        //something for select
    } else if (parentElement.child().type() == 'input'){
        //something for input
    }
}
```

In case you need to know I am only expecting one element either select or input under .info-value

Comment: Get the dom element then get Node Type:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160772/how-to-get-nodetype-using-jquery

Comment: If you expect only one element under `.info-value`, and `.info-value` is the parent of `element`, doesn't that mean `element` _is_ the select or input element? So you can just say `if (element.is('select')){`...

Comment: @nnnnnn : exactly! I am feeling extra dumb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var parentElement = element.parent('.info-value');
if(parentElement.children().is('select')){
    //something for select
} else if (parentElement.children().is('input')){
    //something for input
}
```